# How to monitor all HID incoming and outgoing commands in a service?

Tags: android, service, keyboard, hid

How to monitor HID Commands (incoming or outgoing of the device) in a service in Android? (in this particular problem, keyboard hid code)

Comment: That should not be possible, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Comment: Seems to be out of luck.